# Symfony2 - Dynamic generated form not working while editing form

Tags: symfony

Based on documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

I prepared dynamic generated form. And everything works properly but only when I use form for adding new data (/new) when I use the same form for editing existing data - not working

1. Simple form for "Appointment". It should work like that: User select client and then second "select" is filling proper data - depends on each client from first select. And this works ok but only when I try add new Appointment. When I try edit no.

```
class AppointmentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
                'class'       => 'SystemAdminBundle:Client',
                'placeholder' => '',
            ));
        $formModifier = function(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form, Client $client) 
        {
            $diseases = array();
            if($client !== null) {
                $diseases = $client->getDiseases();
            }
            $form->add('disease', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class'       => 'SystemAdminBundle:Disease',
                    'placeholder' => '',
                    'choices'     => $diseases,
                ));
        };
        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getClient());

            }
        );

        $builder->get('client')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

                $client = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $client);
            }
        );

    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'System\AdminBundle\Entity\Appointment'
        ));
    }
}
```

2. Appointment controller - here is function for add new appointment and edit. For "new" my code works, for "edit" no.

```
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $appointment = new Appointment();
        $form = $this->createForm(AppointmentType::class, $appointment);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {


            $data = $request->request->get('appointment');

            if(array_key_exists('name', $data)) {

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($appointment);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute('appointment_show', array('id' => $appointment->getId()));

            }

        }

        return $this->render('appointment/new.html.twig', array(
            'appointment' => $appointment,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));

    }
    public function editAction(Request $request, Appointment $appointment)
    {
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($appointment);
        $appointment = new Appointment();
        $editForm = $this->createForm('System\AdminBundle\Form\AppointmentType', $appointment);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {

            $data = $request->request->get('appointment');

            if(array_key_exists('name', $data)) {

                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($appointment);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirectToRoute('appointment_show', array('id' => $appointment->getId()));

            }

            return $this->redirectToRoute('appointment_edit', array('id' => $appointment->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('appointment/edit.html.twig', array(
            'appointment' => $appointment,
            'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

3. View for "new" appointment

```
    {% block content %}

    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        
    {{ form_end(form) }}

    
    window.onload = function() {

    var $sport = $('#appointment_client');

    $sport.change(function() {

      var $form = $(this).closest('form');

      var data = {};
      data[$sport.attr('name')] = $sport.val();
      data['appointment[_token]'] = $('#appointment__token').val();

      $.ajax({
        url : $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data : data,
        success: function(html) {

          $('#appointment_disease').replaceWith(

            $(html).find('#appointment_disease')
          );

        }
      });
    });

    };
    
    {% endblock %}
```

4. View for "edit" appointment - it's almost the same as for "new" appointment

```
    {% block content %}
    {{ form_start(edit_form) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
        
    {{ form_end(edit_form) }}

    
    window.onload = function() {


    var $sport = $('#appointment_client');

    $sport.change(function() {

      var $form = $(this).closest('form');

      var data = {};
      data[$sport.attr('name')] = $sport.val();
      data['appointment[_token]'] = $('#appointment__token').val();

      $.ajax({
        url : $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data : data,
        success: function(html) {

        $('#appointment_disease').replaceWith(

        $(html).find('#appointment_disease')
    );   
    }
    });
    });

    };
    
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your `appointment_edit` route takes an id in parameter, but your controller takes an `Appointment` object — how does this even work ?

Comment: Hi, could you solve the problem?? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You create a `new Appointment` in your `editAction` and then persist it. You should take the one that's in your function parameters, handle the request and just flush, since your object is already persisted.

So remove these lines :

```
$appointment = new Appointment();
// ...
$em->persist($appointment);
```

Comment: Yes, I added "$appointment = new Appointment();" by mistake. I removed it but still not working properly.